# Find a recurrence relationship for the following :

Tags: special-functions, fourier-series, legendre-polynomials

Find a recurrence relationhip for $a_{n}$:

$a_{n}=\dfrac {2n+1}{2}\int^{1}_{-1}f\left( x\right) P_{n}\left( x\right) dx$

Where $f\left( x\right)= e^{-x}$

I have done it many times and keep obtianing zero. The hint in the question is to use Rodriguez' formula. And $P_{n}$ is a legendre polynomial.

Comment: What is $P_n(x)$? Is it a legendre-polynomial? You should mention that.

Comment: Rodrigues' formula

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use Integration by parts, where you integrate $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and differentiate $P_n(x)$, then use the Rodrigues' formula.

Comment: Yeah I realise that , however when I am calculating it I keep obtaining zero